# Yii2 kartik GridView " The 'gridview' module MUST be setup in your Yii configuration "

Tags: php, yii2

I have the next trouble,

**The `gridview` module MUST be setup in your `Yii` configuration file and must be an instance of `kartik\grid\Module`.**

I don't know how to configure my config file. In my config file, I have this:

```
'modules' => [

        'gridview' => ['class' => 'kartik\grid\Module']
    ],
```

but this not found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is agregated the line modules over the same herarchy like this:

```
'components' => [
      ],
'modules' => [
     'gridview' => ['class' => 'kartik\grid\Module']
]
```

Comment: in which file in need to add this code. can anyone help me with the file name?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your config file:

```
'modules' => [
    'gridview' =>  [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
    ],
],
```

Comment: The question with almost exact solution has been already replied and chosen 2 days before you

Answer (score -1):

```
backend or frontend -> config -> main.php
```

'modules' => ['gridview' => ['class' => 'kartik\grid\Module']],

Comment: please explain what you are suggesting

Comment: This does not answer the question - OP already has this in its config.

Answer (score -1):

```
'dynagrid' =>  [
    'class' => '\kartik\dynagrid\Module',
    // other settings (refer documentation)
],
'gridview' =>  [
    'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
    // other module settings
],
```

[Reference](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-dynagrid)

Comment: The question with almost exact solution has been already replied and chosen more than 2 years before you